# How to access to only the value of the match RegExp,and not also name, in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a RegExp in javascript and I need to be able to access the value returned to a matching run, I'm using the online tool of Regexp and I saw that this matching works, I also found a "code generator" related to the online tool that produces a code that shows me how to return the values. I also report the values that are returned in the console, I wanted to know, how can I retrieve only the group "value" of these attributes without the name?

RegExp

```
const regex = /\[(\w{1,10}\^\w{1,10}\^\^\w{1,10}|\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\^\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\s\w{1,10}\^\^)\]/gm;
```

String to match

```
const str = `
```

code that is generated automatically by the tool Online Regexp:

```
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
   // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of using forEach, you could use a map...?
`const values =  m.map(match => match)`

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is ok, the exec method will return an array with your found values.

Yo should try to get the index of the group you want, try this way.

```
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
   // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    /*
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
    */
    console.log(`Found: ${m[1]}`);
    //console.log('Found:'+m[1]); //same result/
}
```

Hope this way helps you.